# APLX Char vector to a Integer Vector

Tags: apl

How do I convert from a char vector AKQJT98765 to a vector of integers 13 12 11 10 9 8 7  6 5 using APLX?  I have tried the data conversion function, without succcess.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the question.

If you want to convert a string made of those 10 letters and digits into a vector of the respective integer values (nevermind that in your example the string has 10 characters, but the vector only has 9 numbers) you can use the index function on the reversed string plus an offset:

```
5 + '56789TJQKA' ⍳ X
```

For example:

```
      5 + '56789TJQKA' ⍳ 'ATTAK9'
14 10 10 14 13 9
```

Otherwise, if you wish to convert a string using some known character set, there are a few predefined functions. `⎕UCS` converts a string into a numeric vector and the other way round using the Unicode character values. `⎕TR` is an older function that does something similar, but is system-dependent. `⎕AV` is a vector of all APL characters in their original position (and value.)

Comment: Thank Tobia, Sorry for the Typo, the second vector should have read 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5